# Firebase MessagingService get push Id in onMessageReceived

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm using FirebaseMessagingService. I'm pushing data using NodeJS like below:

```
exports.pushData = functions.database.ref('/Datas/{pushId}').onWrite( event => {
console.log('Push data event triggered');
/* Grab the current value of what was written to the Realtime Database */
    var valueObject = event.data.val();
/* Create a notification and data payload. They contain the notification information, and message to be sent respectively */
    const data = {
        data: {
            from_user: valueObject.from_user,
            to_user: valueObject.to_user
        }
    };
```

This data is storing in the Firebase like:

```
-L7grmlClxCd4ebzaSdo
    from_user: "Joe"
    to_user: "Jack"
```

I'd like to delete this data in some circumstances but I cannot access the push Id in the onMessageReceived listener. I can fetch the data using

```
remoteMessage.getData();
```

However, there is no key (push Id) value in this. Only from_user and to_user are fetching. I need to have the key of this data in the lister to delete this data later. How can I have this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The values of the wildcards in the trigger path are available in [event.params](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/functions.Event#params).

Add that value to the data object you are sending:

```
const data = {
    data: {
        from_user: valueObject.from_user,
        to_user: valueObject.to_user,
        pushId: event.params.pushId // <= ADD
    }
};
```

Comment: sounds great! I'm gonna test it in a couple of hours and let you know about the result. Many thanks.

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank you so much!